# java's inconsistent behavior when handling a utf-8 with BOM string

Tags: java, utf-8

I open my Windows notepad, enter `18`, and save the file as utf-8 encoding. I **know** that my file will have a BOM header, and my file is a utf-8 encoded file(with a BOM header).

Problem is that, when printing that string by below code:

```
//str is that string read from the file using StandardCharsets.UTF_8 encoding
System.out.println(str);
```

In windows I got:

```
?18
```

But in linux I got:

```
18
```

So why the behavior of java is different? How to understand it?

Comment: Whatever way you are getting the text file content into a String is doing it wrong. String is for text. BOM is metadata. Please show code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A BOM is a zero-width space, so invisible in principle.

However Window has no UTF-8 encoding but uses one of the many single byte encodings. The conversion from String to the output will turn the BOM, missing in the charset, into a question mark.

Still Notepad will recognize the BOM and display UTF-8 text.

Linux nowadays generally uses UTF-8, so has no problems, also in the console.

---

***Further explanation***

On Windows `System.out` uses the console, and that console for instance uses as charset/encoding for instance Cp-850, a single byte charset of some 256 characters. Missing might very well be `ĉ` or the BOM char. If a java String contains these chars, they can not be encoded to one of the 256 available chars. Hence they will be converted to a `?`.

Using a [CharsetEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html):

```
String s = ...
CharsetEncoder encoder = Charset.defaultCharset().newEncoder();
if (!encoder.canEncode(s)) {
    System.out.println("A problem");
}
```

Windows generally also runs on a single byte encoding, like Cp-1252. Again 256 chars. However editors may deal with several encodings, and if the font can represent the character (Unicode code point), then everything works.

Comment: if Windows has no UTF-8 encoding, how can we save a file into `utf-8` in the Notepad?

Comment: @ZhaoGang: notepad will handle encoding. Note: I assume Microsoft is pushing much BOM (also on UTF-8), to signal which encoding. I expect than "soon" they will convert to UTF-8 (as user interface), like other operating systems already did.

Comment: BTW: Originally BOM was a zero-width space, but now it should be used only as first code point, as BOM. For real ZWSP, better to use the new U+200B

Comment: Still confused about `Window has no UTF-8 encoding but uses one of the many single byte encodings. The conversion from String to the output will turn the BOM, missing in the charset, into a question mark.` and `Notepad will recognize the BOM and display UTF-8 text.` Could you explain it more? Thx.

Comment: If Notepad can recognize the BOM and display UTF-8 text, why cann't Windows?

Comment: @Joop Eggen Thanks for your answer. Now I think I am quite clear, except for one point: I think Windows code page for Chinese characters should not be one Byte encoding, as there are so many characters in Chinese and 256 characters are far from enough :)

Comment: Another problem is, how can windows know which code page should be used to display the java String? For example: `System.out.println("I love java")` and `System.out.println("我爱Java")`

Comment: @ZhaoGang Sorry that forgot to consider  Chinese, that probably is Big5 or such, not a one byte encoding. In the console, cmd.exe, try the command **`chcp`** to view the code page. In Germany one gets 850, and hence the charset is `Cp850`. (With `chcp` one _could_ also change the current code page.) As a Unicode `String` can combine all scripts, UTF-8 (full Unicode) - as in Linux, would be ideal. For Chinese UTF-16LE (also full Unicode) might be more compact.  GB18030 seems to do Unicode too.

Comment: @JoopEggen with `chcp` I got `936`, which is based on `GBK`, see this link: `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_936_(Microsoft_Windows)`. My understanding is that the `utf-8 BOM` cannot be decoded by cp936 so I got a `?`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of java is the same,  `FileInputStream` do not handle bom.

In windows, your file is  `file1`, file1  hex present is  `EF BB BF 31 38`

In linux, your file is `file2`, file2's hex present is `31 38`

when you read them, you would get different string.

I recommend you convert your bom file to without-bom file with notepad++.

Or you can use [BOMInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html)

Comment: I didn't change the file, just copy it from windows to linux.

Comment: "When you read them, you should get different string", no, you could but should not. A `String` should not contain a BOM, which is the point of the BOMInputStream library your refer to.

Comment: @ZhaoGang  you can use `wc -c yourfilename.txt` or `file yourfilename.txt` to detect the bom.  maybe your transfer tool add bom into your file。